# Passing multiple data in AJAX

Tags: node.js, ajax

Greetings. I wanted to pass multiple data to my server code. Please find the below flow of my program.
HS110:

```
function turnplug2On(){

var newval=this.getAttribute("data-id");
var newval1=this.getAttribute("data-id2");
newval=newval+"On"
console.log(newval);

$(document).ready(function() {   
 //console.log(newval);
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:8124/',
        timeout: 2000,  
        data: JSON.stringify({data:newval}),        

        //data: '{"data":"plug2On"}',
        //data:newval,

    });
});
}
$(document).ready(function () {
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("turn-on")).forEach(function      (button) {
button.onclick = turnplug2On;
});
});

ajax.js:

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
//console.log('request received');
//util.log(util.inspect(req));
console.log(req,res);

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log(chunk.toString());
    //req.on(function (chunk) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(chunk.toString());
    console.log(obj.data);
```

Could you please help me how to pass the object data-id2 to server and how to handle that as a separate data ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var newval=this.getAttribute("data-id");
var newval1=this.getAttribute("data-id2");
 newval=newval+"On"
  console.log(newval);

  $(document).ready(function() {   
 //console.log(newval);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost:8124/',
    timeout: 2000,  
    data: JSON.stringify({newval:newval,newval1:newval1}),        

    //data: '{"data":"plug2On"}',
    //data:newval,

});
});
}
```