# How to access multiple data packet sent from AJAX to nodejs

Tags: node.js, ajax

I wanted to access multiple datapacket that is sent to nodejs
Below is my client code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
 //console.log(newval);
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'http://localhost:8124/',
timeout: 2000,  
data: JSON.stringify({data:newval,data1:newval1}),                
});
});
```

Below is my server code:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
//console.log('request received');
//util.log(util.inspect(req));
console.log(req,res);

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
req.on('data','data1', function (chunk) {
    console.log(chunk.toString());
    //req.on(function (chunk) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(chunk.toString());
    console.log(obj.data);
    console.log(obj.data1);
    var dataval=obj.data;
```

I wanted to get the data1 value so that I can use it for further needs. Could you please guide me in doing that? Thank you in advance

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47319472/passing-multiple-data-in-ajax/47323147#comment81600864_47323147) this question already exists its solved

Comment: Hi , That was solved on how to send data packets. But I am trying receive the request to handle multiple requests. I think both are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written `$(document).ready` this is incorrect.

Either do `document.ready(<FUNCTION HERE>)` OR `$(<FUNCTION HERE>);`

Your client code sends a HTTP request on port 8124. Your Node.js does not listen for incoming requests on port 8124.

You have incorrectly initialised your server.

You need to do `var app = http.createServer(<FUNCTION HERE>)`

Then listen on port 8124 `app.listen(8124,<FUNCTION HERE>);`

In regards to stream handling, I refer you here:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93

Comment: It is actually working for single data. When I handle "data" alone in server code, it is working. I have added the code as well to listen to port 8124 before itself. The only concern is I wanted to handle "data1" as well . Could you please help me ?

Comment: Learn what a stream is and how to deal with streams. Read the article I referred you to. If you still do not understand streams read more.